# How do I change the font size of the button text in my navbar?

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm making a mobile website with jQuery Mobile. In the page I use a navbar with three buttons.
These buttons have a text value of which I would like to change the font size. But I am unsure how to do this, please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include your own style sheet after the jQuery Mobile style sheet.

Use `.ui-navbar .ui-btn-text { font-size: your font-size here; }`